# Are eco-indicator endpoints reported in points or millipoints

Tags: brightway

How do I check if impacts are reported in—for example using 'eco-indicator 99, (H,A)', 'ecosystem quality', 'total'—in milli-points or points.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is stored in `methods`, so you should be able to do the following:

```
In [1]: methods[('eco-indicator 99, (H,A)', 'total', 'total')]['unit']
Out[1]: 'points'
```

You can also see complete method metadata:

```
In [1]: methods[('eco-indicator 99, (H,A)', 'total', 'total')]
Out[1]:
{'abbreviation': 'eco-indicator-99-hatt.418ee316e1a7611c9135b9abe7b490e7',
 'description': 'Implementation of the impact assessment method with the normalized and weighted damage factor. Weights (30% human health, 50% ecosystem quality, 20% resources) and normalization for Egalitarian perspective. Correction of factors for nickel and chromium emissions and nickel and zinc resource. Own assessment for new land use categories.',
 'filename': 'LCIA implementation v3.1 2014_08_13.xlsx',
 'num_cfs': 1285,
 'unit': 'points'}
```